# Is there any functional difference in the regex patterns that jq offers when it comes to selecting an implementation?

Tags: regex, syntax, jq

### Is there any difference between the two following expressions in `jq`?

**Expression 1**

```
match("prefix.*if you do";"gmi")
```

**Expression 2**

```
match(["prefix.*if you do","gmi"])
```

**Findings**

1. They both return the expected data:

   ```
   {
      "caveats": "The command has been installed with the prefix \"g\".\nIf you do not want the prefix, install using the \"with-default-names\"\noption.\n"
   }
   ```
2. Removing the case insensitive (**`i`**) flag or the multi-line flag (**`m`**) on both expressions will cause the match to fail.
3. Using either syntax `[regex,flags]` **or** `regex;flags` works as according to the manual:

   > ```
   > The jq regex filters are defined so that they can be used using one of
   > these patterns:
   >
   > STRING | FILTER( REGEX ) 
   > STRING | FILTER( REGEX; FLAGS )
   > STRING | FILTER( [REGEX] )
   > STRING | FILTER( [REGEX, FLAGS] )
   > ```
4. Mixing the `;` and `,` between the square bracketed versions causes unexpected results.

Technically everything is behaving as expected.

**But are these results circumstantial because of the simplicity of my example** ?

Specifically:

- Is this just convenience syntax ?
- Is there some convention I am missing where the implementation choice is more important than flipping a coin ?
- Is there any functional difference at all between the two versions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a time when multi-arity functions were not supported in jq. I believe that the duality that you describe is a legacy of those days.  Any discrepancy would be a bug worthy of being reported.

(Perhaps some people  got into the habit of typing `[x,y]` rather than `x;y` and preferred the former?)